# How to use a for loop to iterate over dynamically named variables (var1, var2, ...)

Tags: pyqt5

I am trying to make a GUI using PyQt5.
I have a couple of buttons say 4 which call the same function. A click on a button calls the same function to plot the data associated with each button.

```
radiobutton1.clicked.connect(self.fun)
radiobutton2.clicked.connect(self.fun)
radiobutton3.clicked.connect(self.fun)
radiobutton4.clicked.connect(self.fun)
```

Since each line of code is the same except the name of the button, is there a way instead of writing almost the same code four times, I use a for loop to generate the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize them in a loop, then append all of the objects to a list. Then, in this case, all you'd have to do is iterate over the list and call the `.clicked.connect()` method on each object.

```py
radio_buttons = list()

for i in range(1, 5):
    temp_radio_button = QRadioButton("Radio Button")
    radio_buttons.append(temp_radio_button)

....

for radio_button in radio_buttons:
    radio_button.clicked.connect(self.fun)
```

Comment: (Or even `radio_buttons = [QRadioButton("Radio Button") for _ in range(4)] …` - wish I knew off the top of my head why *not* ` [QRadioButton("Radio Button") ]*4`.)

Answer (score 1):

I know it does not apply to this case, but for those who use QtDesigner and need to access the widgets later, this can be an option:

```
def get_all_objects(self,label,window,widget_class):
    for widget in filter(lambda entry: match(label,entry.objectName()),window.findChildren(widget_class)):
        yield widget

for widget in self.get_all_objects('radiobutton',MainWindow,QtWidgets.QRadioButton):
    widget.clicked.connect(self.fun)
```

Note:MainWindow can be replaced by a page on a StackedWidget if all your target widgets are in the same page.